# What is diff b/w scheduleAtFixedRate and schedule:

Tags: java-me

which is more efficient in j2me:

public void schedule(TimerTask task,
                     Date firstTime,
                     long period)

public void scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task,
                                long delay,
                                long period)

what i understand is scheduleAtFixedRate used for long delay and schedule for short delay.

scheduleAtFixedRate  will not see that previous task completed or not , it will start next task at fixed time.

any more diff... plz help.

Answer (score 3):

It is my understanding that the only difference between the two is that `schedule` will run `task` after `delay` milliseconds. After `task` completes it will wait `period` milliseconds before running `task` again. `scheduleAtFixedRate` on the other hand will do the same, but it will run `task`, wait `period` millisecond, and run `task` again, regardless of whether or not the first `task` finished.